Livewire: Custom setAttribute() and setRelation() values disappear after form submit
I am facing an issue with Livewire where the attributes set using setAttribute() and setRelation() methods in the mount() method are missing after the form is submitted.
Trait: HasEloquentModel
trait HasEloquentModel
{
    #[Locked]
    public ?Model $model = null;

    public function getModel()
    {
        if (isset($this->model)) {
            if ($this->model instanceof Model) {
                return $this->model;
            }

            return app($this->model);
        }

        return str(class_basename(static::class))->beforeLast('Component')->prepend('App\\Models\\')->toString();
    }
}

Livewire Component: AssigneeFormComponent
use HasEloquentModel;

public function mount($slug, $id)
{
    $assignee = app(AssigneePost::class); // Pivot Table
    $post = app(Post::class);
    $currentRouteName = Route::currentRouteName();

    if($currentRouteName === 'assignees.create') {

        $post = $post->query()->where(compact('slug', 'id'))->firstOrFail();

        $assignee->setRelation('post', $post);
        $assignee->setAttribute('post_id', $post->id);
        $assignee->setAttribute('user_id', auth()->id());

    } elseif($currentRouteName === 'assignees.edit') {

        $assignee = $assignee->query()->with('post')
            ->where('id', $id)
            ->whereRelation('post', 'slug', '=', $slug)
            ->firstOrFail();
    }

    $this->model = $assignee;

    //...
}

public function attemptSubmit()
{   
    $validated = $this->validate();
    $this->getModel()->fill($validated)->save();

    //...
}

When the form is edited, the post_id and user_id fields remain unchanged. However, for a new form of Assignee, we retrieve the post_id and user_id from the mount() method, while outside of it, they remain unchanged. The form contains fields such as content, type, status, approved_at, approved_by, etc., validated after form submission. After successful submission, all fields including post_id and user_id are saved in the database. But, I encountered an error:

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'post_id' doesn't have a
default value

When I dd($this->getModel()) after form submission, the custom set attributes are missing.
$assignee->setRelation('post', $post); // -----------> Missing
$assignee->setAttribute('post_id', $post->id); // -----------> Missing
$assignee->setAttribute('user_id', auth()->id()); // -----------> Missing

